# Distinct duplicate rows based on one property

Tags: sql, database, linq

I have the following data:

```
ID| TimeStamp| Data
-------------------
 1| t+1      |A
 2| t+2      |B
 3| t+3      |A
 4| t+4      |A
 5| t+5      |D
```

I want to get all unique rows, based on Data. If there are some values next to each other, i want to get the newest one (TimeStamp).

My desired result:

```
ID| TimeStamp| Data
-------------------
 1| t+1      |A
 2| t+2      |B
 4| t+4      |A
 5| t+5      |D
```

Row with ID 3 should be filtered (t+4 > t+3) but ID 1 should remain (because there is Data B between).

How would a query for this look like in sql/linq?

Comment: is this sql server?

Comment: Yes. But i also want to recreate it with linq.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `lead()`:

```
select id, timestamp, data
from (select t.*, lead(data) over (order by timestamp) as next_data
      from t
     ) t
where next_data <> data or next_data is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT *
    FROM your_table YT1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM your_table YT2 yt2.data = yt1.data
        AND yt1.id = yt2.id + 1
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with Linq:

```cs
class Row
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

var testData = new List<Row>
{
    new Row { Id = 1, Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-5), Data = "A" },
    new Row { Id = 2, Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-4), Data = "B" },
    new Row { Id = 3, Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-3), Data = "A" },
    new Row { Id = 4, Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1), Data = "A" },
    new Row { Id = 5, Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2), Data = "A" },
    new Row { Id = 6, Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-0), Data = "D" },
};

var orderedData = testData.OrderBy(row => row.Timestamp); //The list needs to be in correct order for the where statement to work.

var filteredResult = 
    orderedData.Where((row, i) => 
        i + 1 == testData.Count || row.Data != testData[i + 1].Data); //Current row is last row OR Data of current row is different from next row.

foreach (var row in filteredResult)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"ID: {row.Id}, Timestamp: {row.Timestamp}, Data: {row.Data}");
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to create that in just one query? I have a big database and want to avoid an "download" of all data before. The filtering should be executed without saving all before (reference to testData/orderedData).

Comment: @JanMöller: 1. Methods can be chanied together. So the variable `orderedData` is not needed. 2. More impotantely the query constructed by Linq is only executed when the data is actually consumend. In my example the `OrderBy` and `Where` statements themselfe don't read any data. Only when the program reaches the `foreach` loop the data is read. Search for "linq deferred execution" for more info.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention, that i have to access data via a DBContext. Do you know, how i can "translate" the expression "testData[i+1]"? I am not able to access an element of this context list directy without consuming it before, am i (dynamic position)?

Comment: @JanMöller: If the `IDs` are in order and without hole, as they are in your example data, you should be able to access the next element with `testData.Single(r => r.Id == row.Id + 1)`. Otherwise I don't know enough about Line to SQLServer. Maybe it's possible to the the index with the `row_number()` SQL-function. But I have now idea how to include that into a linq query.